# How to remove item from listview populated by a database but don’t remove from the database

Tags: android, database, listview, cursor

I have two activities. The first contains a list of strings that will be populated onClick from rows in a database, the second activity displays all rows in a database from which you pick from.

The idea is to pick 15 players for a sports team from the players on the database.

What I want to do is remove the player that has been picked from the list in the second activity once it has been clicked i.e. so I cannot pick the same player twice.

Here are my activities:

```
public class PickTeamActivity extends Activity {

ListView listView;
String[] values;
String context;
Bundle extras;
public static final String PREFS = "examplePrefs";

Button finish;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pickteam);

    SharedPreferences exmaple = getSharedPreferences(PREFS, 0);
    context = exmaple.getString("teamName", "cant find team");

    extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    // Get ListView object from xml
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewPlayers);

    // Defined Array values to show in ListView
    values = new String[] { "No.1 ", "No.2 ", "No.3 ", "No.4 ", "No.5 ",
            "No.6 ", "No.7 ", "No.8 ", "No.9 ", "No.10 ", "No.11 ",
            "No.12 ", "No.13 ", "No.14 ", "No.15 "

    };

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
    // Assign adapter to ListView
    View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer_view, null);
    listView.addFooterView(v);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    finish = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_finishPicking);
    finish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent i = new Intent(PickTeamActivity.this, OptionsActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);  
        }
    });
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            // ListView Clicked item index
            int itemPosition = position;

            // ListView Clicked item value
            String itemValue = (String) listView
                    .getItemAtPosition(position);

            // Show Alert
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    "Position :" + itemPosition + "  ListItem : "
                            + itemValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // .................................................................................

            Bundle passdata = new Bundle();
            passdata.putInt("position", itemPosition);
            passdata.putString("value", itemValue);

            Intent passIntent = new Intent(PickTeamActivity.this,
                    ViewMatchPlayersActivity.class);
            passIntent.putExtras(passdata);
            startActivityForResult(passIntent, 0);

        }

    });


}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    finish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent i = new Intent(PickTeamActivity.this, OptionsActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);  
        }
    });
    //TODO handle here. 

    Bundle b = data.getExtras();
   // ArrayList<Integer> removeList  = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int i = b.getInt("row");
    int p = b.getInt("previous_pos");
    String v = b.getString("previous_val");
    MySQLiteAdapters regadapter = new MySQLiteAdapters(this);
    Cursor c = regadapter.queryRecord(i);

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            values[p] = v + ": " + c.getString(0) + " " + c.getString(1);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }

    ArrayList<Integer> removeList  = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    removeList.add(i);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer_view, null);
    listView.addFooterView(view);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            // ListView Clicked item index
            int itemPosition = position;

            // ListView Clicked item value
            String itemValue = (String) listView
                    .getItemAtPosition(position);

            // Show Alert
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    "Position :" + itemPosition + "  ListItem : "
                            + itemValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // .................................................................................

            Bundle passdata = new Bundle();
            passdata.putInt("position", itemPosition);
            passdata.putString("value", itemValue);

            Intent passIntent = new Intent(PickTeamActivity.this,
                    ViewMatchPlayersActivity.class);
            passIntent.putExtras(passdata);
            startActivityForResult(passIntent, 0);

        }

    });
}

public void onBackPressed()
{
    Intent i = new Intent(PickTeamActivity.this, OptionsActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);  
}
```

}

public class ViewMatchPlayersActivity extends Activity {

```
ListView nameList;
MySQLiteAdapters adapter_ob;
MySQLiteHelper helper_ob;
SQLiteDatabase db_ob;
Button registerBtn;
Cursor cursor, cursor2, cursor3;
String val, team;
int pos;
String[] removeList;
public static final String PREFS = "examplePrefs";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_match_players);
    nameList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    adapter_ob = new MySQLiteAdapters(this);

    SharedPreferences exmaple = getSharedPreferences(PREFS, 0);
    team = exmaple.getString("teamName", "cant find team");
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    pos = extras.getInt("position");
    val = extras.getString("value");

    String[] from = { helper_ob.KEY_FNAME, helper_ob.KEY_LNAME,
            helper_ob.KEY_POSITION, helper_ob.KEY_TEAMNAME };
    int[] to = { R.id.tv_fname, R.id.tv_lname, R.id.tv_position,
            R.id.tv_teamName };
    cursor = adapter_ob.queryName(team);
    SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.row, cursor, from, to);

    nameList.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
    nameList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            //ArrayList<Integer> removeList  = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            Cursor listCursor = (Cursor) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
            int playerRecord = listCursor.getInt(listCursor
                    .getColumnIndex("p_id"));
            //removeList.add(playerRecord);

            adapter_ob.playerPicked(playerRecord, "YES", pos + 1);

            Bundle passdata = new Bundle();
            passdata.putInt("row", playerRecord);
            passdata.putInt("previous_pos", pos);
            passdata.putString("previous_val", val);

            Intent passIntent = getIntent();
            passIntent.putExtras(passdata);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, passIntent);
            finish();
        }
    });
 }
}
```

As you can see I am getting the list of players from the database here:

```
 cursor = adapter_ob.queryName(team);
```

I want to somehow edit that list and remove the records that have selected previously using the row ID which I get here:

```
int playerRecord = listCursor.getInt(listCursor
                .getColumnIndex("p_id"));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am about to go to bed and don't have time to look into this fully, but just to maybe give you some idea. All adapters have a `remove` method which takes an object argument.

So if you can get the object you want to remove using `playerRecord` then you can remove from the adapter with the `remove` method and call `notifyDataSetChanged` on your adapter to update your restults.

Otherwise you might want to write a custom adapter and implement your own remove method which removes the item from the custom adapters datasource.

Comment: hey did you get a chance to look into this more?

Comment: I think the best way to do this would be to create yourself a custom adapter. That way you can write your own method to handle removing certain items from the list. There is a good tutorial here on how to create a custom adapter for list views http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: SimpleCursorAdapter does not have a remove(); method

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix this will a little more thinking.

what I did was change `cursor = adapter_ob.queryName(team);` to take in a string also 
i.e.`cursor = adapter_ob.queryName(team, string);`

and changed the queryName(); method to not return the records from the string and not display them i.e.

```
public Cursor queryName(String team, String filter2) {
    String[] context = {team};
    opnToWrite();
    Cursor mCursor = database_ob.rawQuery("SELECT PLAYER_Local._id AS p_id, * FROM PLAYER_Local, TEAM_local " 
            + "WHERE PLAYER_Local.team_id = TEAM_local._id "
            + "AND team_name = ? "
            + "AND  p_id not in ("+filter2+")" 
            + "ORDER BY first_name ", context);

    return mCursor;
}
```

this Line; `"AND  p_id not in ("+filter2+")"`, the **not in**.

I populated the initial string by making use of the **SharedPreferences** class and creating a List< String > and added the id of the record to the list every time an item was clicked, then converted the list to a string to be stored by the **SharedPreferences**. I then pulled teh string down when i needed it.

Full classes shown below.

```
public class PickTeamActivity extends Activity {

ListView listView;
String[] values= new String [15];
String context;
Bundle extras;
Editor editor;
SharedPreferences exmaple;
String previousContext;
public static final String PREFS = "examplePrefs";

public Button finish;

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle changedState) {

      changedState.putStringArray("array", values);
      //common bug fix
      changedState.putString("WORKAROUND_FOR_BUG_19917_KEY", "WORKAROUND_FOR_BUG_19917_VALUE");
      super.onSaveInstanceState(changedState);
    }

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pickteam);

    exmaple = getSharedPreferences(PREFS, 0);
    context = exmaple.getString("teamName", "cant find team");

    //extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    // Get ListView object from xml
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewPlayers);

    // Defined Array values to show in ListView
      if(savedInstanceState != null){
          values = savedInstanceState.getStringArray("array");
      }
      else{
          int size = exmaple.getInt("array_size", 15);
            for(int i1=0; i1<size; i1++)
                values[i1] = exmaple.getString("array_" + i1, "No." + (i1 + 1)); 
      }
      //add values to sharedPrefs
        editor = exmaple.edit();
        editor.putInt("array_size", values.length);
        for(int x=0;x<values.length; x++)
            editor.putString("array_" + x, values[x]);
        editor.commit();

    //call custom method
    onListItemClick();


}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode ==RESULT_OK){
          Bundle b = data.getExtras();  
        int i = b.getInt("row");
        int p = b.getInt("previous_pos");
        MySQLiteAdapters regadapter = new MySQLiteAdapters(this);
        Cursor c = regadapter.queryRecord(i);

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                values[p] = "No." + (p+1) + ": " + c.getString(0) + " " + c.getString(1);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }

        editor.remove("array_" + p);
        editor.putString("array_" + p, values[p]);
        editor.commit();

        onListItemClick();
        System.out.println("resultcode = " + "RESULT OK");
    }else{
        System.out.println("resultcode = " +"RESULT NOT OK");
    }
}

public void onListItemClick() {
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
    // Assign adapter to ListView
    View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer_view, null);
    listView.addFooterView(v);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    finish = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_finishPicking);

    finish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent i = new Intent(PickTeamActivity.this, OptionsActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);  
        }
    });
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            // ListView Clicked item index
            int itemPosition = position;

            // ListView Clicked item value
            String itemValue = (String) listView
                    .getItemAtPosition(position);

            // Show Alert
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    "Position :" + itemPosition + "  ListItem : "
                            + itemValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // .................................................................................

            Bundle passdata = new Bundle();
            passdata.putInt("position", itemPosition);
            passdata.putString("value", itemValue);
            passdata.putString("teamContext", context);

            Intent passIntent = new Intent(PickTeamActivity.this,
                    ViewMatchPlayersActivity.class);
            passIntent.putExtras(passdata);
            startActivityForResult(passIntent, 0);

        }

    });
}

//public void onBackPressed()
//{
//  Intent i = new Intent(PickTeamActivity.this, OptionsActivity.class);
//  startActivity(i);  
//}
```

}

```
public class ViewMatchPlayersActivity extends Activity {

ListView nameList;
MySQLiteAdapters adapter_ob;
MySQLiteHelper helper_ob;
SQLiteDatabase db_ob;
Button registerBtn;
Cursor cursor, cursor2, cursor3;
String val, team;
Editor editor;
int pos;
String filter;
List<String> removeList;
public static final String PREFS = "examplePrefs";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_match_players);
    nameList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    adapter_ob = new MySQLiteAdapters(this);

    SharedPreferences exmaple = getSharedPreferences(PREFS, 0);
    team = exmaple.getString("teamName", "cant find team");
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    editor = exmaple.edit();
    pos = extras.getInt("position");
    val = extras.getString("value");

    String[] from = { helper_ob.KEY_FNAME, helper_ob.KEY_LNAME,
            helper_ob.KEY_POSITION, helper_ob.KEY_TEAMNAME };
    int[] to = { R.id.tv_fname, R.id.tv_lname, R.id.tv_position,
            R.id.tv_teamName };

    String test = exmaple.getString("removePlayers", "notFound");

    if (test.equals("notFound")){
        removeList = new ArrayList<String>();
        filter = removeList.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(", ", ",");
        editor.putString("removePlayers",filter );
        editor.commit();

    }else{
        filter = exmaple.getString("removePlayers", "ERROR");
    }

    if (filter.length()== 2 || filter.length()== 3){
        filter = filter.substring(1);
    }

    cursor = adapter_ob.queryName(team, filter);

    SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.row, cursor, from, to);

    nameList.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
    nameList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            //ArrayList<Integer> removeList  = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            Cursor listCursor = (Cursor) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
            int playerRecord = listCursor.getInt(listCursor
                    .getColumnIndex("p_id"));
            //removeList.add(playerRecord);

            adapter_ob.playerPicked(playerRecord, "YES", pos + 1);
            removeList = new ArrayList<String>();
            removeList.add(filter);
            removeList.add(Integer.toString(playerRecord));
            filter = removeList.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(", ", ",");
            editor.putString("removePlayers",filter );
            editor.commit();

            Bundle passdata = new Bundle();
            passdata.putInt("row", playerRecord);
            passdata.putInt("previous_pos", pos);
            passdata.putString("previous_val", val);

            Intent passIntent = getIntent();
            passIntent.putExtras(passdata);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, passIntent);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

}